# Add another fork in github. Do not merging. It is a parallel project

Tags: git, github

Well, some years ago I uploaded a old open source game to github https://github.com/mdtrooper/ardentryst_reborn.

And today, I found a guy who uploaded the same old game https://github.com/hhirsch/ardentryst.

And I want to add or link the repositories for to show the relationship between the repositories in networkmap, and the important thing, send pull requests to the guy.

But I don't know how do I this action.

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub it's not possible to compare two unrelated repos. For PR's and other things fork is required